# Use useEffect to manage the state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a program that takes and displays `contacts` from an array, and we have an `input` for searching between contacts, which we type and display the result.
I used `if` in the search function to check `if` the `searchKeyword` changes, remember to do the `filter` `else`, it did not change, `return contacts` and no filter is done
I want to do this control with `useEffect` and I commented on the part I wrote with `useEffect`. Please help me to reach the solution of using `useEffect`. Thank you.

*In fact, I want to use `useEffect` instead of `if`*

*I put my code in the link below*

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-child-parent-comp-forked-4qf39?file=/src/App.js:905-913

Comment: What is the purpose/point of using an `useEffect` hook to do the filtering? Are you going to store also this filtered result into component state to be passed along to `Contact`?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, this is exactly what I want to do in useEffect, if the change in searchKeyword is to run the handleFilterContact, but there was no change, only the contacts return that the contacts in the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

In the `useEffect` hook in your sandbox you aren't actually updating any state.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const handleFilterContact = () => {
    return contacts.filter((contact) =>
      contact.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchKeyword.toLowerCase())
    );
  };
  return () => contacts;
},[searchKeyword]);
```

You are returning a value from the `useEffect` hook which is interpreted by React to be a hook cleanup function.

See [Cleaning up an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)

## Solution

Add state to `MainContent` to hold filtered contacts array. Pass the `filtered` state to the `Contact` component. You can use the same `handleFilterContact` function to compute the filtered state.

```
const MainContent = ({ contacts }) => {
  const [searchKeyword, setSearchKeyword] = useState("");
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(contacts.slice());

  const setValueSearch = (e) => setSearchKeyword(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleFilterContact = () => {
      if (searchKeyword.length >= 1) {
        return contacts.filter((contact) =>
          contact.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchKeyword.toLowerCase())
        );
      } else {
        return contacts;
      }
    };

    setFiltered(handleFilterContact());
  }, [contacts, searchKeyword]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter a keyword to search"
        onChange={setValueSearch}
      />
      <Contact contacts={contacts} filter={filtered} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit use-useeffect-to-manage-the-state-in-react]

### Suggestion

I would recommend against storing a filtered contacts array in state since it is easily derived from the passed `contacts` prop and the local `searchKeyword` state. You can filter inline.

```
const MainContent = ({ contacts }) => {
  const [searchKeyword, setSearchKeyword] = useState("");

  const setValueSearch = (e) => setSearchKeyword(e.target.value);

  const filterContact = (contact) => {
    if (searchKeyword.length >= 1) {
      return contact.fullName
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchKeyword.toLowerCase());
    }
    return true;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter a keyword to search"
        onChange={setValueSearch}
      />
      <Contact contacts={contacts.filter(filterContact)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I read somewhere that you should not use if inside `useEffect`, is this true? And is using the `if` in `useEffect` the right thing to do?

Comment: @Good I've not ever heard that, and see no reason why you'd limit perfectly valid javascript in any React hook callback function. Is it the right thing to do? Sure, I don't see another simple way to branch logic on the length of the search input. You are either filtering results or including the entire set.

Comment: For better code, is it better to use this part of the code with `useEffect` or the same way I wrote it first?
Thanks for all the tips and for sharing your information with me :)

Comment: @Good IMO it's best to store in state the only filtering conditions, i.e. the `searchKeyword` in your case, and pass the conditions and filter inline *before* mapping. See this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-useeffect-to-manage-the-state-in-react-forked-cqbuy?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Finally do you think I should use `useEffect` for my code or the way you wrote for `if`?

Comment: @Good I don't think the `useEffect` hook is the best option. It will certainly work but just adds unnecessary additional moving parts. I'd go with your first non-useEffect solution, or my addendum which is similar in functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234103/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-good).